# Assigning an array value into a multidimensional numpy array based on an equality comparison condition?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, numpy-ufunc

I am new to numpy multidimentional arrays, and getting stuck on what seems like it should be an "easy" concept.

In the code below, `fakepng` represents an RGBA image inside of a numpy array. I want to set the alpha channel to `0` for of every pure black pixel `[0,0,0]` of that image to make them transparent.  I can do this with nested for loops:

```
fakepng = np.array([[[0,0,0,255],[0,255,255,255]],[[255,255,0,255],[255,255,255,255]]])
rows, cols, channels = fakepng.shape
for x in range(0, rows):
    for y in range(0, cols):
        if (fakepng[x, y, 0] == 0 and fakepng[x, y, 1] == 0 and fakepng[x, y, 2] == 0):
            fakepng[x, y] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

However, I'm getting lost trying to find the "right" numpy function and/or syntax to make this a 1 line and efficient operation.  I'm not sure if this is a indexing or masking problem, if I need a vectorized function, or what the best concept would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the annoyingly slow for loops you can do the following:

```py
# 1. Create an auxiliary 2D array
aux_fakepng = fakepng.reshape(-1, 4)

# 2. Find all the rows in which all the elements but the last are 0
idx_rows = np.all(aux_fakepng[:, :-1] == 0, axis=1)

# 3. Set the alpha channel of those rows to 0
aux_fakepng[idx_rows, -1] = 0
```

Notice that you are modifying `aux_fakepng`. Since you have two references pointing to the same array, every modification that you make to `aux_fakepng` will also affect `fakepng`.

**EDIT**

Since some people may be new to `numpy` and multidemnsional arrays, I will try to explain as good as I can what is going on here.

First, we start by creating a new reference which will point to `fakepng`. During the process, we're also reshaping the array, so it's easier to work with it:

```py
aux_fakepng = fakepng.reshape(-1, 4)
```

When we are reshaping our array, we specify that the new shape is going to be `(-1, 4)`. This means that our new reference will have **4 columns** and that it will try to fit the number of rows as best as it can considering the other dimensions of the original array. Note that this operation might fail in the case that it can't fit a perfect array, which is an array in which all rows have 4 columns.

In case that a channel had more or less values instead of 4, we could do the following:

```py
aux_fakepng = fakepng.reshape(-1, fakepng.shape[-1])
```

By doing this we are using the last value of `fakepng`'s value (which refers to the number of channels).

This assignment, as said before, creates a new reference to the original array. This means that every modification made to `aux_fakepng` is also going to affect `fakepng`, since they are the same object. This assignment is not a deep copy (there are functions like `np.copy()` which allow to crate a deep copy of an array).

Once we have a 2D array, we need to find the rows where all RGB values are equal to 0. To find these rows, we can do the following:

```py
idx_rows = np.all(aux_fakepng[:, :-1] == 0, axis=1)
```

But, what is going on here? What is `aux_fakepng[:, :-1]` supposed to do? Let's take a step back first.

Currently, this is `aux_fakepng`:

```py
array([[  0,   0,   0, 255],
       [  0, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255,   0, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255]])
```

Here, we are selecting **ALL ROWS** (: part) and in each row we are selecting **ALL COLUMNS EXCEPT FOR THE LAST ONE** (:-1 part). So, what we are accessing is the following array:

```py
array([[  0,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255, 255],
       [255, 255,   0],
       [255, 255, 255]])
```

Now, we compare whether each elements equals to 0 or not by doing `aux_fakepng[:, :-1] == 0`. This returns the following array:

```py
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False]])
```

However, we want to find the rows where all elements are 0, not where the array equals to 0. To do so, we use the `np.all()` function and we apply it along `axis=1`. This means that the function will check that all elements accross the rows are 0. Please refer to [this page](https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/numpy-axes-explained/) if you want a better understanding on `numpy` axis. The function produces the following output and assigns it to `idx_rows`:

```py
array([ True, False, False, False])
```

Finally, we change the alpha channel's value of those rows where we have found a black pixel in (`[0, 0, 0]` value) to 0:

```py
aux_fakepng[idx_rows, -1] = 0
```

By doing this, we are accessing the rows whose indexes correspond to the positions of `idx_rows` where a `True` value is found. Inside those rows we are accessing to the last element (-1 index), which corresponds to the alpha channel, and we set its value to 0.

Comment: Thanks - this code worked.  A better answer might explain more about that indexing notation syntax and why it does what is expected.

Comment: Hi again, I've modified the original answer. There you can find a better explanation on what's going on! I hope you find it helpful :)